# Two loadbalacer with apache 2.2(for jboss and apapche tomcat)

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss

I have a apache server with loadbalancer(apache-2.2) and two tomcat nodes(clusters). To communicate with tomcat nodes I'm using mod_jk. I've defined two loadbalancer in apache(by changing httpd.conf and worker property files). Apache is running in port 80. The configuration as follows. iSencer is one of my application.

```
In httpd.conf
=============
Listen localhost:80
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/home/xx/projects/apache/content" (I've created a seperate root directory as content)

JkMount /iSencer       loadbalancer
JkMount /iSencer/      loadbalancer
JkMount /iSencer/*     loadbalancer

In worker.properites
====================
worker.list=loadbalancer

#------------------------
# iSencer node 1 - tomcat
#------------------------
worker.iSencer1.type=ajp13
worker.iSencer1.host=localhost
worker.iSencer1.port=8109

#------------------------
# iSencer node 2 - tomcat
#------------------------
worker.iSencer2.type=ajp13
worker.iSencer2.host=localhost
worker.iSencer2.port=8010

# ------------------------
# Load Balancer for yard
# ------------------------
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
worker.loadbalancer.balanced_workers=iSencer1,iSencer2
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.method=B
```

and there are some changes in tomcat server.xml.So, cluster is working properly.
Now I want to add a jboss server to same apache. But need to run in different loadbalancer. My changes as follows as in httpd.conf in apache.

```
JkMount /index.html loadbalancer2
JkMount /servlet/*  loadbalancer2

worker property
===============
worker.list=loadbalancer, worker.list=loadbalancer2

#------------------------
# tracker node 1
#------------------------
worker.track.port=8009
worker.track.host=localhost
worker.track.type=ajp13
worker.track.lbfactor=1
worker.track.connection_pool_size=10

# ------------------------
# Load Balancer for tracker
# ------------------------
worker.loadbalancer2.sticky_session=1
worker.loadbalancer2.balanced_workers=track
worker.loadbalancer2.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer2.method=B
```

But after adding jboss to apache as a cluster my tomcat cluster is not working properly ? In browser it will show two JSESSIONIDs. When I remove jboss form apache configuration still not working. Browser still showing two JSESSIONIDs. After clearing cookies in browser cluster is working fine. so what is the reason not to work cluster with jboss ?